# Clamav False Positive and Linux Viruses statistics

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamav, clamtk

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10.

After to use Clamav (with Clamtk GUI) to scan my PC, I found a lot of LibreOffice files, macros mostly, which Clamav shows as "Possible dangerous threats". But, I guess it is just a "False Positive", because those files are here from the "Official" LibreOffice installation which, I guess, was tested by the Ubuntu community.

But... Just in case... Is there some "Official" web page where we could find all the known Linux viruses status (real known malware, etc)? Is there something like this, where? ???

Comment: ClamAV doesn't just find virus/malware - it can find lots of things which maybe of concern to privacy zealots, but are things those most of us don't really concern ourselves with (we put filters on our internet if we are somewhat concerned anyway).  It won't be virus files I bet, but your settings have told it to highlight everything (including possible report-home detail isn't strictly malware but design decisions).  *This is vague, I recall being concerned after a scan & looked up the reason for the reports years ago; this is what I recall of the why - i lowered ClamAV detection levels*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some "Official" web page where we could find all the known Linux viruses status (real known malware, etc)? Is there something like this, where? ???

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Linux_vulnerability) has a good run down on threats and the likes and [they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Viruses) also keep a list of virus and other malware (the list is not complete but there are 27 noteworthy). None of them you will find on your system as most "never left the laboratory ". Most will work but require effort from the owner of the machine to make it work (like actually downloading and installing the virus yourself).

There is a more detailed description on [unixmen](https://www.unixmen.com/meet-linux-viruses/) on the most important. Do look at the dates: most are ancient. Security updates are quick to arrive on our machines so if someone found a security hole it will be plugged quickly.

If you start looking for an actual list: do not trust the owners of virus scanners. They make up stuff. A lot. Just to make you sell their scanners.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rinzwind, for all your excellent data!!!